# XamlReader with Click Event

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamlreader

I am using *XamlReader* in my WPF project. And it works ([My reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx))

My current sample Xaml is like that:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="800" Height="600">
  <Button Name="Test1" Content="Test1" Width="357" Height="88" Margin="14,417,0,0" ></Button>
  <Button Name="Test2" Content="Test2" Width="357" Height="88" Margin="14,529,0,0" ></Button>
</Grid>
```

and adding button's click event like this:

```
button = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(rootObject, "Test1") as Button ;
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Button1_Click);
```

Is it possible to write xaml like this?

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Width="800" Height="600">
  <Button Name="Test1" Content="Test1" ... Click="Button1_Click"></Button>
  <Button Name="Test2" Content="Test2" ... Click="Button2_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You can by binding a command, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531935

Comment: You can by binding a command, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XamlReader.Load` not allowed to attach `eventHandlers` in it. so use this technique to dynamically attach the `eventHandlers` to it.

1- Write your Xaml string without `eventHandlers` -But write the Name property of those Controls.

2- Load the string with `XamlReader.Load(str);`

3- Then load the content of DataTemplate from it. using `Grid template = ((Grid)(dt.LoadContent()));`

Note: here `Grid` is the parent Control in `DataTemplate`.

4- Find the Control by Name you want to attach the Event Handler.
`Button img = (Button)template.FindName("MyButtonInDataTemplate");`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't save events or load them at run-time using raw XAML. It's a limitation of XAML Serialization, as serialized XAML is self-contained, means every resource should be in raw XAML to load and event's code logic is not . Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx#Event_Handling_is_Not_Preserved)

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. I suppose, I can not add _Template_ property too.