# WPF Button Command binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, icommand

I have a `MainWindow:Window` class which holds all the data in my program. The `MainWindow`'s .xaml contains only an empty TabControl which is dynamically filled (in the code-behind).

One of the tabs (`OptionsTab`) has its `.DataContext` defined as the `MainWindow`, granting it access to all of the data. The `OptionsTab` has a `DataGrid` which has a column populated with `Buttons`, as shown below:

[image]

The `DataGrid` is populated with `DataGridTemplateColumns`, where the `DataTemplate` is defined in the main `<Grid.Resources>`. I would like to bind this button to a function in the `MainWindow` (not the `OptionsTab` in which it resides).

When the `OptionsTab` is created, it's `.DataContext` is set as the `MainWindow`, so I would have expected that defining the `DataTemplate` as below would have done it.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeadLoadIDColumn">
    <Button Content="{Binding Phases, Path=DeadLoadID}" Click="{Binding OpenDeadLoadSelector}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I thought this would mean the Click event would be bound to the desired `OptionsTab.DataContext = MainWindow's` function.This, however, didn't work (the `Content` did, however). So then I started looking things up and saw [this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531935/2175231) (by Rachel, who's blog has been of great help for me), from which I understood that you can't {bind} the click event to a method, but must instead bind the `Command` property to an `ICommand` property (using the helper `RelayCommand` class) which throws you into the desired method. So I implemented that, but it didn't work. If I place a debug breakpoint at the `DeadClick` getter or on `OpenDeadLoadSelector()` and run the program, clicking on the button doesn't trigger anything, meaning the {Binding} didn't work.

I would like to know if this was a misunderstanding on my part or if I simply did something wrong in my implementation of the code, which follows (unrelated code removed):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Main"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WPF" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<TabControl Name="tabControl"
            SelectedIndex="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, ElementName=Main}">
</TabControl>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ICommand deadClick;
    public ICommand DeadClick
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == deadClick)
                deadClick = new RelayCommand(p => OpenDeadLoadSelector());
            return deadClick;
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
    public static DependencyProperty TabsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tabs", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainWindow));
    public ICollectionView ITabsCollection
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(TabsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TabsProperty, value); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<NPhase> Phases = new ObservableCollection<NPhase>();
    public static DependencyProperty PhasesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Phases", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainWindow));
    public ICollectionView IPhasesCollection
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(PhasesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PhasesProperty, value); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Loads = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public static DependencyProperty LoadsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Loads", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainWindow));
    public ICollectionView ILoadsCollection
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(LoadsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadsProperty, value); }
    }
    
    void OpenDeadLoadSelector()
    {
        int a = 1;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        var optionsTab = new TabItem();
        optionsTab.Content = new NOptionsTab(this);
        optionsTab.Header = (new TextBlock().Text = "Options");
        Tabs.Add(optionsTab);
        ITabsCollection = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tabs);

        Loads.Add("AS");
        Loads.Add("2");

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**OptionsTab.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF.NOptionsTab"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WPF">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DeadLoadIDColumn">
            <Button Content="{Binding Phases, Path=DeadLoadID}" Command="{Binding Path=DeadClick}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
    <l:NDataGrid Grid.Row="2"
                 x:Name="PhaseGrid"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <l:NDataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date (days)" Binding="{Binding Path=Date}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Deadload" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DeadLoadIDColumn}"/>
        </l:NDataGrid.Columns>
    </l:NDataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**OptionsTab.xaml.cs**

```
public NOptionsTab(MainWindow w)
{
    DataContext = w;
    InitializeComponent();
    PhaseGrid.ItemsSource = w.Phases;
}
```

---

While we're at it (and this might be a related question), why does `{Binding Phases, Path=DeadLoadID}` work on the `DataTemplate` (which is why the buttons appear with "Select"), but if I do `{Binding Phases, Path=Name}` in the PhaseGrid and remove the `.ItemsSource` code from the constructor, nothing happens? Shouldn't the PhaseGrid inherit its parent's (NOptionsTab / Grid) `DataContext`? Hell, even setting `PhaseGrid.DataContext = w;` doesn't do anything without the `.ItemsSource` code.

**EDIT (27/04/14):**

I think that knowing the contents of the `NPhase` class itself will be of use, so here it is:

```
public class NPhase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string name;
    double date;
    string deadLoadID = "Select";
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            EmitPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public double Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set
        {
            date = value;
            EmitPropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }
    public string DeadLoadID
    {
        get { return deadLoadID; }
        set
        {
            deadLoadID = value;
            EmitPropertyChanged("DeadLoadID");
        }
    }
    void EmitPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
    public NPhase(double _date, string _name)
    {
        date = _date;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

**EDIT (29/04/14):**

A simplified project (getting rid of everything that wasn't necessary) can be downloaded from here (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3087637/WPF.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is the problem that you do not specify data source properly for the data item inside your grid.

I think that the data source for your button column is **NPhase** instance. So it has no **DeadClick** property. So, you can check it using `Output` window in Visual Studio.

I suggest that you can do something like that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DeadLoadIDColumn">
    <Button Content="{Binding Phases, Path=DeadLoadID}"
            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeadClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type l:NDataGrid}}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I currently do not understand how you can compile **Content="{Binding Phases, Path=DeadLoadID}"**, because as I thought the default value for **Binding** clause is the **Path** property, and you have specified it twice.

**EDIT**
After I got the small solution all becomes clear. [Here](http://yadi.sk/d/vbKCfSiUNhXWL) is the modified solution. All what I changed in it - I have added **RelativeSource** to the command binding as I described above, and I added MainWindow as DataContext for your OptionsTab (you have specified it in the question, but not in the project). That's it - all works fine - the command getter is called, and the command is executed when you click the button.

Comment: Phases is an `ObservableCollection<NPhase>` property, so for the column I have to bind it to this collection and then, for each cell (or row), bind it to the `NPhase.DeadLoadID` property. `{Binding Phases.DeadLoadID` doesn't work because `.DeadLoadID` isn't a property of the collection, but yes of the individual elements of the collection. I've edited the OP with the code for NPhase, which might help to clear things up.

Comment: Can you tell me the type of `DataContext` for that `Button`?

Comment: In addition to strange Binding [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413(v=vs.100).aspx): "The Binding markup extension uses Binding.Path as a conceptual "default property", where Path= does not need to appear in the expression."

Comment: The button has no defined `DataContext` and therefore inherits it from its parent, which has `MainWindow` as its DataContext (see `OptionsTab` constructor).

And I don't know how else I could define the binding, since the standard `{Binding Phases.DeadLoadID}` wouldn't (and doesn't) work, since Phases doesn't contain a property .DeadLoadID, only Phases[i] does.

Also, the main question here is regarding binding the Command property to an ICommand, which I can't seem to get working.

Comment: Have you tried solution with **RelativeSource** attribute?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention it, but yes, and still no go. :( It compiles but nothing happens. I also tried changing AncestorType to `l:MainWindow` but that didn't work and I also tried removing the entire `RelativeSource` bit, keeping just the `Path=DataContext.DeadClick`, but that didn't do it either.

Comment: You should to provide us with solution, where the problem is reproduced, and we get you the answer.