# How to select an item in a ListBox and pick the item's name from a DataTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am implementing a Download UI in WPF,  where every file that is being downloaded will be shown inside a list box in a `DataTemplate`

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate> 
         <TextBlock x:Name="FileName" text={Binding FileName}" />
         <ProgressBar ... />
         <Button Content="Cancel" click="ButtonCancel_Click" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox>
```

Now this List is getting populated with all the download information perfectly. Only problem I am having is that when user clicks on `Cancel` button, to cancel the download, I have to remove an entry from the `ObservableCollections`. But I don't have the `File Name` in the click event( I know click event is not MVVM, still I want to do it in click event handler).

Can anyone suggest how do I get the `FileName` of that particular file when the `selectedItem` gets cancelled. in The

```
private void ButtonCancel_Click(...) {}
```

Comment: I don't understand your description, nor the question. Please correct the description to be more precise.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do it in code-behind, in button click event handler, if your application implemented using MVVM ?

Comment: Ok, tell me how do I do it command binding... actually its a POC, Not a full fledge dev, that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would still encourage you to use [`MVVM` way of dealing with UI events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531772/binding-button-click-to-a-method), here's how you can achieve what you want, using `Cancel` button's click event handler.

First in your xaml, `bind` file name to `Cancel` button's `Tag` property.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate> 
         <TextBlock x:Name="FileName" text={Binding FileName}" />
         <ProgressBar ... />
         <Button Content="Cancel" Tag="{Binding FileName}" 
                 Click="ButtonCancel_Click" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<ListBox>
```

Then in your click event handler

```
private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
   Button myButton = (Button)sender;
   string fileName = myButton.Tag.ToString();
   // use fileName
}
```

**Edit**

Just to add a complete example, that was tested locally, and ensured that works.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="FileName" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />

                         <Button Content="Cancel" Tag="{Binding Path=FileName}" 
                                 Click="ButtonCancel_Click" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var fileNames = new List<DownloadModel>
            {
                new DownloadModel
                {
                    FileName = "File1"
                }, 
                new DownloadModel
                {
                    FileName = "File2"
                }, 
                new DownloadModel
                {
                    FileName = "File3"
                }
            };

            listBox1.ItemsSource = fileNames;
        }

        private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myButton = sender as Button;
            if (myButton.Tag == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tag value was null.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File name is {0}", myButton.Tag));
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadModel
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `string fileName = myButton.Tag.ToString();` the `Tag` is `null`. Its throwing exceptions.

Comment: @Debhere then associated `FileName` is also null, and `TextBlock` also shouldn't have any file name. Just add a check to see if `myButton.Tag` is not null, before calling `ToString()` on it.

Comment: Sorry, I it got resolved, I forget to put the `Tag="{Binding Path=FileName}"`, now its working. But Can you give an example if I do it in Command Binding, how it should be, Consider that Command Class is already implemented,

Comment: Follow [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363568/Command-binding-with-Events-a-way-from-simple-to-a), it is pretty straightforward.