# INotifyPropertyChanged and Button.IsEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have View and its ViewModel. In View, I have some Panels that has binding to some properties in my ViewModel;

For example first property is `SomeObject`. In that panel I have some textboxes, that has binding to some properties in `SomeObject` class. All bindings in ViewModel and classes implements INPC.

That textbox, in panel, has binding to its property in `SomeObject` class this way: `SomeObject.Property`.

In that view I have a Save button. I need change the `IsEnabled` property of my button every time when something was entered in textboxes or changed in panel.

I've done it only for `SomeObject` property in my viewmodel by changing `IsEnabled` property bound to button from  SomeObject's setter. But when I change something in properties of my `SomeObject` it doesn't call the setter of main `SomeObject` in ViewModel, and I can't change my `IsEnabled` property from `SomeObject` class.

```
<controls:ExpandableSettingsPanel Header="REFUND" IsExpanded="{Binding RefundCustomerConfigurationEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" ..>
    <StackPanel..>
        <CheckBox Content="Allowed within reversal period" IsChecked="{Binding RefundCustomerConfiguration.IsAllowedWithinReversalPeriod, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource GrayTextBlockStyle}" Text="Minimal amount to be refunded"/>
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="€" .. />
            <controls:MementoTextBox Text="{Binding RefundCustomerConfiguration.MinimalAmountToBeRefunded, Mode=TwoWay, 
                NotifyOnValidationError=True, StringFormat=\{0:N2\}, 
                TargetNullValue='', 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, 
                ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"  ..>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors:TextBoxInputRegExBehavior 
                            EmptyValue="0.00"
                            IgnoreSpace="True"
                            RegularExpression="^\d{1,2}(\.?\d{1,2})?$" 
                            MaxLength="6"
                            />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </controls:MementoTextBox>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource GrayTextBlockStyle}" Text="Minimal bank statement line age" ../>
        <controls:MementoTextBox Text="{Binding RefundCustomerConfiguration.MinimalBankStatementLineAge, 
            Mode=TwoWay,
            NotifyOnValidationError=True,
            ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
            ValidatesOnExceptions=True }" ..>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:TextBoxInputRegExBehavior 
                        EmptyValue="0"
                        IgnoreSpace="True"
                        RegularExpression="^\d{1,3}$" 
                        MaxLength="3"
                        />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </controls:MementoTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</controls:ExpandableSettingsPanel>
```

This is my XAML part.

```
public RefundCustomerConfiguration RefundCustomerConfiguration
{
    get { return _refundCustomerConfiguration; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _refundCustomerConfiguration, value);
        OnPropertyChanged("RefundCustomerConfigurationEnabled");
    }
}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public bool IsAllowedWithinReversalPeriod
{
    get { return GetValue(() => IsAllowedWithinReversalPeriod); }
    set
    {
        SetPropertyValue(value);
    }
}
```

And this is my properties; First - in ViewModel. Second - in first property class.

Comment: This looks like a puzzle :) You should share a part of code

Comment: Provide us your code, so we can find the error

Comment: It sounds like what you need to learn to use is the `ICommand` interface, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF.

Comment: Can you include the XAML for your Save button? It should bind to a `SaveCommand` in the ViewModel, and the `ICommand` interface provides you with a `CanExecute` check which is automatically used to enable/disable the button bound to the command. There's an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3531935/302677) if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind button's visibility property to the Visibility method in the class which realize INotifyPropertyChanged interface as like this:

```
public Visibility btnVisible
{
   get
   {
      if(<your condition>)
         return Visibility.Visible;
      else
         return Visibility.Collapsed;
   }
}
```