# Bind RequestNavigate method of Hyperlink control in Wpf Rich Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink

I have a very simple screen which shows some content and a hyperlink. As the hyperlink is spread over multiline I can't use WPF button as it would move the whole link into a new line which is not acceptable by the client.

This is a Caliburn micro MVVM application and I handle the process of opening the link in my method in the view model. I don't want to use code-behind thus need to bind the RequestNavigate event of the hyperlink.

Code for rich textbox is

```
 <RichTextBox FontSize="13"  BorderThickness="0" IsDocumentEnabled="True" IsReadOnly="True" Block.TextAlignment="Center"  Width="270">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                Download Failed. Please
                <Bold>check your connection and try again or</Bold>
                <Hyperlink >contact your provider</Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Output is

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your view model code?

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlink implements `ICommandSource` interface, so you can use it's Command property to bind to a Command on ViewModel, just like you would with a Button.

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding MyNavigationRequestedCommand}">contact your provider</Hyperlink>
```

I guess you're familiar with implementation since you mentioned you would use a Button, but here is a [link to an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531772/binding-button-click-to-a-method#answer-3531935) here on SO. If you need to handle RequestNavigate event specifically, you can use `EventTrigger` + `InvokeCommandAction` from `System.Widnows.Interactivity`as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897775/wpf-binding-ui-events-to-commands-in-viewmodel#answer-4897897).