# Binding Checkbox Click event inside ItemsControl to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, data-binding

I have an `ItemsControl` that creates `CheckBox`es based on `DigitalFilterSubsystems`. I want to trigger an event handler on the viewmodel whenever a `CheckBox` is clicked. At them moment my `Click` property of the `CheckBox` is complaining that `Checked_Triggered` is expecting a property. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong and show a solution?

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding DigitalFilterSubsystems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>        
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>           
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding }" Foreground="Black" FontSize="12"/>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="{Binding Path=Checked_Triggered, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vm:SimulatorControlViewModel}}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>   
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>            
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In my viewmodel called `SimulatorControlViewModel`:

```
public void Checked_Triggered(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    
}
```

Comment: This is not MVVM...Do you know about commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot *bind* an event handler to an event in XAML. Even if it was possible, your binding would be wrong. Your view model is set as the `DataContext` of a control, but `RelativeSource` is used to refer to *controls*. What you would do is specify the type of the parent control as `AncestorType`, that has the desired data context set and specify the property path like `DataContext.YourPropertyToBind`, e.g.:

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.MyIsCheckPropertyOnTheViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
```

Now to the core of your issue, executing an action in the view model if the `CheckBox` `Click` event is raised. There are multiple options, depending on your requirements.

### Expose a Property

If the items in your `DigitalFilterSubsystems` are a custom type, e.g. `Subsystem`, you can expose a property `IsChecked` (or give it a more meaningful name for what checked means). In the setter of the property, call a method that acts on the current value of the property.

```
public class Subsystem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private bool _isChecked;

   public bool IsChecked
   {
      get => _isChecked;
      set
      {
         if (_isChecked == value)
            return;

         _isChecked = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
         OnCheckedChanged();
      }
   }

   private void OnCheckedChanged()
   {
      if (IsChecked)
         // ...do something.
      else
         // ...do something.
   }

   // ...other code.

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Then simply bind the property in XAML to `IsChecked` of `CheckBox`.

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

### Use a Command

You can use a command to encapsulate the logic and expose it as a bindable object. For that you need a *relay command* or often called *delegate command* implementation. You can read about the details of these concepts in the following article.

- [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand)

A relay command simply takes an action that it encapsulates as an object and optionally a *can execute* predicate that determines if the action can be executed. This object can be exposed from a view model and bound in XAML. Relay commands implement the `ICommand` interface and WPF knows how to handle it.

You can copy a relay command implementation from anywhere, there are plenty of implementations, most MVVM frameworks already provide their own. If you have chosen one, expose a command property in your `SimulatorControlViewModel` and initialize it in the constructor with the method to be called (this could vary depending on the concrete command implementation that you use).

```
public class SimulatorControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public SimulatorControlViewModel()
   {
      Clicked = new RelayCommand(ExecuteClicked);
   }

   public ICommand Clicked { get; }

   private void ExecuteClicked(object isChecked)
   {
      if ((bool)isChecked)
         // ...do something.
      else
         // ...do something.
   }

   // ...other code.

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Then bind the `Clicked` command to the `Command` property of the `CheckBox` and bind the `CommandParameter` to its own `IsChecked` property (this is the parameter that is passed to the `ExecuteChecked` method.

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding Clicked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

### Use a Behavior to Call A Method

You can install the [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/) NuGet package, which contains `CallMethodAction` that allows a method to be called on an object when an event is raised.

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <b:Interaction.Triggers>
      <b:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
         <b:CallMethodAction MethodName="Checked_Triggered" TargetObject="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
      </b:EventTrigger>
   </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

Caution: The method signature must match `public void Checked_Triggered()` exactly (`public`, return `void` and no arguments), otherwise you will get an exception stating that the method was not found.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot bind to a method that way, you can only bind to properties. Depending on whether you are using some kind of MVVM framework there could be a solution offered by that framework. Another way would be to use a binding to a command property defined in your viewmodel. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531935/1213316