# Need help understanding MVVM Tutorial, RelayCommand & Use of lambdas

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, icommand

I am reading Josh Smith' [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) tutorial

i don't understand what the below code is trying to do.
First, the syntax reminds me properties, but with add/remove instead.

But what is `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`?

> It delegates the event subscription to
>   the CommandManager.RequerySuggested
>   event. This ensures that the WPF
>   commanding infrastructure asks all
>   RelayCommand objects if they can
>   execute whenever it asks the built-in
>   commands

```
//Figure 3 The RelayCommand Class
public class RelayCommand : ICommand 
{ 
#region Fields 
    readonly Action<object> _execute; 
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute; 
#endregion // Fields
#region Constructors 
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) 
{ } 
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute) 
{ 
    if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute"); 
   _execute = execute; 
   _canExecute = canExecute; 
} 
#endregion // Constructors 
#region ICommand Members 
[DebuggerStepThrough] 
public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
{ 
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter); 
} 
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged 
{ 
    add    { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; } 
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; } 
} 
public void Execute(object parameter) 
{ _execute(parameter); } 
#endregion // ICommand Members }
```

Also, save command is configured with lambdas. 1st, there are 2 param variables. 
Will they conflict? i cannot just do something like `RelayCommand(this.Save(), this.CanSave)` or is there no such syntax.

```
_saveCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Save(),
                                param => this.CanSave );
```

Comment: This could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281566/is-josh-smiths-implementation-of-the-relaycommand-flawed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value` means that if the function for `CanExecute` can resolve to both `true` and `false` depending on some conditions.

   WPF will disable the `Button/MenuItem` (`CommandButtonBase`) if it evaluates to `false` and enable whenever the condition evaluates to `true`.
   If you don't have those two lines, WPF will ask the command only once (when the **Button/MenuItem** is loaded and will not update after that unless you do it manually.
2. The two parameters (lambda-expressions) are of type `Action<object>` and a `Predicate<object>` respectively. So, they cannot, by definition, conflict (`params` is just a name - and as the two functions have different scope - they don't conflict).

   If you have a method with the right signature, you can use that in the constructor

   - `private void Save(object obj)`
     and
     `private bool CanSave(object obj)`

   respectively, but you shouldn't have the `()` at the end - so new `RelayCommand(this.Save,this.CanSave)` should work.

Comment: 1 thing i dont understand about `CanExecuteChanged` is the add/remove. it looks like to me a getter/setter, when i add an event handler for `CanExecuteChanged` i also add it to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event. same for remove? but you say value can evaluate to true/false. so what is the add/remove actually? also assuming value is bool, how will `CommandManager` know which control to disable?

Comment: The add/remove is what happens everytime something adds a command.CanExecuteChanged += SomeRoutine (and -= of course). So, everytime the WPF engine adds a handler to the command (that's what happens when you add it to a button's Command property behind the scenes), we add a hook to CommandManager - this hook contains the value (ie. the button) and the Command - and then afterwards when CommandManager decides enough has changed that CanExecute could be different - it tells the Button to ask the Command for the new CanExecute - thus dis-/enabling the button accodringly.