# How to create and implement a custom command?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was primarily following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF

But then I realize the `RelayCommand` is part of another framework that I can't use. This is the code I have:

```
    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private bool CanExecuteTestCommand()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername);
    }

    private void CreateTestCommand()
    {
        TestCommand = new TestCommand(TestExecute, CanExecuteTestCommand);
    }

    public void TestExecute(object parameter)
    {
        obj.TestConnection();
    }
```

And the XAML:

```
<Button Content="Test Connection" Command="{Binding Path=TestConCmd}" />
```

But this won't compile because `TestCommand` is, obviously, an invalid type.

I've looked over this tutorial as well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM

But similarly, `Command` doesn't seem to be a type even though I've added `using System.Windows.Input`.

Then all the other tutorials I've looked at just use built-in commands like closing the application, pasting from the clipboard and a few other things like that.

So... How do I actually create my command?

Comment: You could just go to the link in this article and download the source of MVVM Light Toolkit to see it's implementation. http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight (PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs. But a word of warning: Trying to start with MVVM without a proper and matured MVVM Framework will be a pain in the ass and you'll do yourself a favor by using one of the matured frameworks in your projects if you don't want to reinvent every single thing

Comment: @Tseng Due to outrageous security policies at work I can't download almost anything. Also, it's an extremely simple app that I'm re-writing from C++. It's just a single form that processes a bunch of text files and writes some stuff to a database. Internal use only. Nothing too demanding or requiring of a "matured framework", really. Mostly just taking this as an opportunity to learn new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`Command` is not a type, `ICommand` is. You must derive from/implement it:

```
public class TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
       //Do stuff
    }
}
```

And subsequently implement the methods, especially `Execute(object parameter)`. Then you can do:

```
TestCommand = new TestCommand();
```

in your View Model as before. Of course, you can re-implement RelayCommand or something like it. [Is Josh Smith's implementation of the RelayCommand flawed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281566/is-josh-smiths-implementation-of-the-relaycommand-flawed) Shows some code and easy to make mistakes.

Comment: So then does this `TestCommand` class need an instance of my actual model so that it can call TestConnection on that object? Seems kind of weird, to me.

Comment: @sab669 Possibly, if you don't do a generic `Delegate/RelayCommand` then you would have to pass a `TestConnection` object for it to act on to it in your example. If you *do* pass a delegate to it, of course the assigned method could have access to that variable.