# One View Model for multiple buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM. I'm trying to sort out how to have a clean project structure where there are multiple buttons that launch different apps (like chrome, IE, notepad). Is it possible to have one ViewModel for multiple buttons?

I have started by using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase), and my attempt at a solution is to make the code from that link the view model base and have other view models for each button that extend said base.

Each one has a unique action:

```
    public override void ClickAction()
    {
        Process ieProcess = new Process();
        ieProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "IExplore.exe";
        ieProcess.Start();
    }
```

However, I'm unsure of the proper way to go about doing this. How do I create a DataContext with this approach? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why does each button have its own data context to start with? Unless you are in an items control, that doesn't sound right.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Like I said, I'm new to this and having a hard time grasping the design pattern. Can you make a suggestion on what I should do differently/how to approach this?

Comment: Two suggestions, in fact :)

Comment: Fantastic. Clearly I need many suggestions :) Looking for as many as you've got. For me, this is not an easy design pattern to get used to!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have one View Model per View; not per item in your view (in this case, buttons). An easy way to do what you are describing would be to use the `CommmandParameter` property to pass in your exe names:

```
<Button Content="Launch IE" Command="{Binding LaunchAppCommand}" CommandParameter="IExplorer.exe"/>
<Button Content="Launch Notepad" Command="{Binding LaunchAppCommand}" CommandParameter="notepad.exe"/>
<Button Content="Launch Chrome" Command="{Binding LaunchAppCommand}" CommandParameter="chrome.exe"/>
```

With your command:

```
public ICommand LaunchAppComand {get; private set;}
...
public MyViewModel()
{
    LaunchAppCommand = new DelegateCommand(LaunchApp);
}
...
private void LaunchApp(object parameter)
{
     string processName = (string)parameter;
     Process launchProc = new Process();
     launchProc.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
     launchProc.Start();
}
```

To avoid hard coding all your buttons you could use an `ItemsControl`, which does set an individual data context for each template it creates. To do so, you need a collection of data classes, and a slightly different way to get to your command:

```
//ProcessShortcut.cs
public class ProcessShortcut
{
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
    public string ProcessName {get; set;}
}

//MyViewModel.cs, include the previous code

//INotifyPropertyChanged left out for brevity
public IEnumerable<ProcessShortcut> Shortcuts {get; set;} 

public MyViewModel()
{
    Shortcuts = new List<ProcessShortcut>()
    {
        new ProcessShortcut(){DisplayName = "IE", ProcessName="IExplorer.exe"},
        new ProcessShortcut(){DisplayName = "Notepad", ProcessName="notepad.exe"},
        new ProcessShortcut(){DisplayName = "Chrome", ProcessName="chrome.exe"},
    };
}

//MyView.xaml
<Window x:Name="Root">
...
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shortcuts}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Button Content="{Binding DisplayName, StringFormat='{}Start {0}'}" 
                      Command="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=DataContext.LaunchAppCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding ProcessName}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
...
</Window>
```

Because an `ItemsControl` sets the `DataContext` inside the template to the bound item you need an `ElementName` binding to get to the command, and don't need to qualify access to members of `ProcessShortcut`. In the long run, this is the approach you usually want to take when you have repetitious controls like this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Definitely a great explanation and start for my learning process! I found an implementation of DelegateCommand online that seems sufficient, do you have any input/advice about this? It seems there is no Microsoft implementation of it.

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld The online implementations are ususally fine; but their implemention of `CanExecuteChanged` is exceptionally inefficient if they use CommandManager.RequerySuggested (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3408591/1783619). As long as you avoid that most of them are good

Comment: Okay, thanks again! Currently there's something wrong with the click command binding, it's not triggering any of the LaunchAppCommand calls. I'll look into it for a while and post a follow up later if I can't get it. You've been very helpful

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld Check for `System.Data` errors in your output; they should point you to where your binding syntax is wrong (also, make sure you set the DataContext of the view to your view model)

Comment: I'm  a bit confused, LaunchApp() is never called, but the buttons are bound to the LaunchAppCommand. How are these two related? Is it called 
behind the scenes somehow or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld Yes; but not as "behind the scenes" as you may think! You passed `LaunchApp` into the `DelegateCommand` that `LaunchAppCommand` is bound to. When you click the button, the `Execute` method of the command is called by the framework (really, the `Button` class; you can see it on reference source), which in turn calls the delegate you passed into it. Make sense?

Comment: Hmm. I understand what you mean, makes sense. It's still not working for some reason. When I add debug breakpoints, none of them get hit when I click the buttons.

Comment: The error I receive is:`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LaunchAppCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MyView' (Name='Root')'. BindingExpression:Path=LaunchAppCommand; DataItem='MyView' (Name='Root'); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: @AlexRosenfeld Whoops, forgot to path through the datacontext on the items control version! Check my updated path