# Why people use CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() on ICommands?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making some custom ICommand implementation of my own and I see A LOT of implementations going like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{        
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

As far as I can see this is poorly optimized code since calling `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` will trigger ALL commands in the UI to check their `ICommand.CanExecute` status, when usually we just want one of them to verify it.

I think I read once this is the main code of some WPF ICommands like `RoutedCommand`, and for them it makes sense because they want to revalidate all ICommands automatically once some control loses focus and things like this, but still I don't understand why people repeat this pattern for their own `ICommand` implementations.

The code I have in mind is a simple event invocation such as:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{        
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I tested and this works, so **Why all the examples on the web don't implement something as simple as this? Am I missing something?**

I have read about memory leak problems using strong references in regular events, where the `CommandManager` only uses `WeakReferences`, which is good in case the View is Garbage Collected, but still, **aren't there any solutions that won't compromise performance over memory footprint?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281566/is-josh-smiths-implementation-of-the-relaycommand-flawed

Answer (score 7):

> Why all the examples on the web don't implement something as simple as this? Am I missing something?

I'm guessing it's mostly due to laziness... What you propose is indeed a better (more efficient) implementation. However, it's not complete: you still need to subscribe to `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` to raise `CanExecuteChanged` on the command.

Comment: Why? I tested this and it works... Which case scenarios am I missing?

Comment: @mFeinstein, "it works" in the cases you're tested, but calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` won't raise the `CanExecuteChanged` on your command.

Comment: @mFeinstein, but it should. That's the whole point of calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`: to ensure the `CanExecute()` of all commands is re-evaluated. You're right that the command itself shouldn't call it, but other code can (and does) call it.

Comment: I thought "if I raise the CanExecuteChanged" so the command will look for its "CanExecute" status... But not that this is the only way of making the command reevaluate it. I thought the CommandManager holds a reference to the command and it will reevaluate, but not necessarily with the event bring triggered.

Comment: "I thought the CommandManager holds a reference to the command": no, it doesn't; it only has a (weak) reference to the event handler if you subscribe to the `RequerySuggested ` event.

Comment: "it will reevaluate, but not necessarily with the event bring triggered": how, then? If the command is bound to a control, the control needs to know that it needs to update its enabled/disabled state. It does so by subscribing to the `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the obvious answer, but I am not familiar with the inner WPF engine, there could be a lot more to it, specially on the CommandManager side of things. I usually try to not make any assumptions before I know more about a system.

Comment: Ideally, a command should both react to `RequerySuggested`, and expose a `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method. This way it can be refreshed globally or individually.

Comment: So `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` should be implemented with a `WeakReference` to avoid memory leaks and be more performant than `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`, right?

Comment: @mFeinstein `CommandManager` uses a weak reference because it's long-lived (static event), but it's not the case for an individual command, so it doesn't need to use a weak reference.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's my typical implementation: https://gist.github.com/thomaslevesque/13c3e69f6c5ae219b945fc07b75843fc

Comment: Well, if a viewmodel triggers some UI reconstruction the strong reference could be an issue I guess and something easy to forget and not pay the proper attention.

Comment: Your code looks just like mine, but I didn't made the CommandManager part, good job!

Comment: I was just looking your code a second time...shouldn't you unregister from the `RequerySuggested` event on the Command's destruction?

Comment: @mFeinstein it doesn't really matter, because `RequerySuggested` only holds a weak reference.

Comment: Oh, yeah, hahah I forgot and it's the whole point of the question hahaha

Answer (score 4):

Very simply - if you are performing heavy work in `ICommand.CanExecute()` then you are using `Commands` very badly. If you follow that rule there should in fact be no serious performance implication to calling `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.

Pragmatically, it's a much easier implementation than what you've suggested.

Personally, I rather call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` in a particular `ViewModel` when a property changes so that the feedback to the user is instantaneous (i.e. enabling a button as soon as a form is completed/valid).

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your point, how a 5 line solution can be "programmatically easier" than a 3 line solution?

Comment: It's simpler because you don't have to have each change call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on every `Command` that is affected by that property.

Comment: In that sense it is, but IMHO it's flawed in its concept. RaiseCanExecuteChanged I believe is for the ViewModel to be able to notify that particular Command, and only him, that his CanExecute state changed. CommandManager is the one to notify all. I can't imagine any programming case where activating all objects in the purpose of activating one is considered good practice. It's like yelling at the street so everyone will open the door, instead of ringing at the door bell of the door you want.... But still, I understand the simplicity IF you kept your CanExecute simple and has few commands.

Comment: I can. Try the text/paragraph formatting bar of a Word processing application. If your document and formatting command host are completely separate `ViewModel` classes, you would use `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` because there is no way you would want to have dependencies to multiple `ViewModel`/`Command` classes and have to manually maintain those relationships.

Comment: In that case I think you would want a special kind of command that behaves like this, not that all commands should be like this.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, it's 2019 now, but I have found another reason to use CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested().

I have written my own custom ICommand class for a WPF application, in which I invoked CanExecuteChanged directly in the first place like this.

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, null); 
}
```

My WPF application makes heavy use of different threads and when the above method is called from another thread then the main UI thread, it throws no error, it is just kind of ignored. It was getting even worse, when I found out, that all code lines inside the calling method were skipped, which led to strange results.

I don't know exactly, but I guess the reason was, that CanExecuteChanged led to changes in my UI, which must not be changed from another thread.

However - the moment when I changed my ICommand to CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(), there was no more problem. It seems that CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() can be called from any thread and the UI still gets updated.

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

I thought this could be a valueable answer, because I debugged this issue for 3 hours, before I came to this solution. The problem finding this issue was, that there were no errors thrown while debugging. The code was just skipped. Very strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382413/12885902). It is true that the `CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, null);` has to be called by the main UI thread.

Simply write it like follows:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, null)); 
}
```

This solves your problem and you can requery just one command. It is however true that you should nevertheless make your `CanExecute`-Method as fast as possible, as it will anyways be periodically executed.
It is best to have CanExecute just consist of a single `return foo;` where `foo` is a field you can set right before you call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the simpler solution for a long time and haven't seen any problems. I tested with .NET 4.7 and the events are unsubscribed. So I see no point in using `CommandManager`

```
public class CanExecuteTestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CanExecuteTestViewModel()
    {
        AddCommand = new MyCommand(_ => Item = new Item());
        RemoveCommand = new MyCommand(_ => Item = null);
        TestCommand = new MyCommand(delegate { });
    }

    public MyCommand AddCommand { get; }
    public MyCommand RemoveCommand { get; }
    public MyCommand TestCommand { get; }

    private Item _item;
    public Item Item { get { return _item; } set { _item = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Item))); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
public class Item { }

public class MyCommand : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public MyCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    private event EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { _canExecuteChanged += value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubscriberCount))); }
        remove { _canExecuteChanged -= value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SubscriberCount))); }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => _canExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute.Invoke(parameter);
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int SubscriberCount { get { return _canExecuteChanged?.GetInvocationList().Length ?? 0; } }
}
```

and ui

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.CanExecuteTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="root"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CanExecuteTestViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestCommand.SubscriberCount}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Item}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
                    <Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand, ElementName=root}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```